# How to programmatically tell the matplotlib plot window to save and close

Tags: python, matplotlib

This snippet opens the plot window and it stays open until I click to close it. How do I tell Matplotlib to save the graphic and close the window?

```
# From https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-pyplot-py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()  # This code blocks until the plot window is closed.
```

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but having an external window opening has to do with the IDE you're using and not with `matplotlib` per se. You might want to check some option to show plot in the console instead of an external windows, so you don't have to close them.

Comment: What exactly is the desired behaviour? Not to open a window in the first place? Or open it, then directly close it? Or leave it open for 10 seconds?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  Not to open a window in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [plt.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) instead of `plt.show()` if you want to save the figure instead of display it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

plt.savefig('fig.png')
```

Comment: Great user name.  "I'm going to give you the only name you spelled correctly.
From this day forward, your name shall be- - ''Max Power''?

Comment: Thanks! haha glad you got it

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib allows you to save figures easily without opening the window, use the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```